# h:panelgrid with multiple columns in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

How can I hide the first  column of h:panelgrid  ( with columns 2) and automatically increase the width of second column to fit the entire panel grid in JSF 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Have two panelgrids and use rendered - use the one that fits for the situation. Or use EL and evaluate "columns" on the server side. I suppose columnClasses could also get evaluated like this to get dynamic style.